# How to use WMI to get GPU info?

Tags: winapi, wmi, wmi-query

I want to use wmi to get the GPU info in a program written in Go.I know use the https://godoc.org/github.com/StackExchange/wmi can do it,and here is a function named "func Query".But, i don't know how to edit the "query string".Somebody can help me ? Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go. Just [do this](https://www.google.com/search?q=WMI+GPU).

Comment: BTW the 1st resource there suggests using [this](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wmie) which claims to support «utomatic generation of WQL query for the selected Class/Instance.», so basically you may run that tool, do a few mouse clicks then copy and paste the query it will have generated for you.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
import (
    "github.com/StackExchange/wmi"
)

type gpuInfo struct {
    Name string
}

func getGPUInfo() {
    var gpuinfo []gpuInfo
    err := wmi.Query("Select * from Win32_VideoController", &gpuinfo)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("gpu:",gpuinfo[0].Name)
}
```