# How can I get application's usage of graphics card through winapi?

Tags: c, windows, go, winapi, graphics

there is a problem with me that I want to get some application's usage of graphics card, like frame rate, rending time per frame , caton rate ...

I want to use some windows api in my code to get it ,but I do not know how.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perhaps this can be a starting point? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526742/how-to-use-wmi-to-get-gpu-info

Comment: if its your app you can measure the times inside your code ... see [OpenGL GPU times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37490211/2521214) and [Windows CPU times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21509808/2521214) and you can also use RDTS instruction if on x86/x64 CPU ...

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you could try to use WMI and [Win32_VideoController class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-videocontroller?redirectedfrom=MSDN).